# How does this method nesting work? [TableRowRenderingTip.java]

Tags: java, tablecellrenderer

When looking for something on the java documentation I realized there's some kind of nesting I've never seen before, so If you could explain what is it or how is it called I would be very grateful.

It's my first question in StackOverflow so I'm sorry if I broke any rule.

Code:

```
private JComponent createData(DefaultTableModel model)
{
    JTable table = new JTable( model )
    {    //What are these brackets for? I know it contains a method but I've never seen a method "nested" with a variable initialization.
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
        {
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

            //  Color row based on a cell value

            if (!isRowSelected(row))
            {
                c.setBackground(getBackground());
                int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                String type = (String)getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 0);
                if ("Buy".equals(type)) c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                if ("Sell".equals(type)) c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }

            return c;
        }
    };
```

Don't really know how to properly use the question editor.

Thanks in advance!

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) the full source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have found is called as anonymous class. In the example it extends `JTable` class, but because it do not want to use it multiple times it does not give a name to the new class (hence anonymous), instead it creates an instance of it instantly, and stores it in the `table` variable.
In the new class it overrides the `prepareRenderer` method of the original `JTable`.

Here you can read more about anonymous classes:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!